# python: several functions in one file, AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am a beginner of python, and I just created a module file in python which includes several functions together. When I called the first function defined in the file, it was fine. But when I tried to call the second function it says:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file2file'` (file2file is a function I defined by myself)

Here is the code of the file

```
import sys
import scipy as sci
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np

def file2map(inf):
    dic = dict()
    with open(inf, "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            s = line.split("\t")
            dic[(int(s[0]),int(s[1]))] = float(s[2])
    return dic

def file2file(inf,outf):
    with open(inf, "r") as fin:
        with open(outf, "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            s = line.split("\t")
            fout.write("t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n",s[0],s[1],s[2])
```

the file's name is `dataprocessing.py`, when I typed `dataprocessing.file2map('xxx.data')`, it is fine, but generated an error message of `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file2file'` when I typed `dataprocessing.file2file('xxx.data','out.data')`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If running in the interactive interpreter, did you `reload(dataprocessing)` after changing the file?

Comment: I copied your code and cannot reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the thing that causes your error, but I see that you missed an indent in the most inner for loop in `file2file(inf,outf)`

It should be:

```
def file2file(inf,outf):
    with open(inf, "r") as fin:
        with open(outf, "w") as fout:
            for line in fin:
                s = line.split("\t")
                fout.write("t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n",s[0],s[1],s[2])
```

Comment: @user2579376 show us how are you trying to use your functions